# Function unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

I've a program where there's a function called stt.stt() that recognize the speech, I'm from Spain so I have to remove tildes and turn the text that stt.stt() into unicode, to do that i have this function:

```
def remove_tildes(s):
   return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')) #Remove spanish tildes so there won't be errors with ascii
phrase=remove_tildes(stt.stt())
```

But when I run the program, I get this error:

```
File "./program2.py", line 14, in remove_tildes
    return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')) #Remove spanish tildes so there won't be errors with ascii
TypeError: must be unicode, not None
```

To fix this I have tried with `phrase=remove_tildes(basestring(stt.stt(), unicode))`, `phrase=remove_tildes(u stt.stt())` an with `phrase=remove_tildes(unicode stt.stt())`
But nothing works, I've also read this https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html but I still don't know what should I do to fix this
Could someone help me?

Comment: what exactly is `c`? Does `stt.stt()` return something?

Comment: `s` is `None`, most likely.

Comment: stt.stt() Returns a text that is wich you've spoken
I didn't write the function, as I'm starting with this i got it from a web page, how should it be?

Comment: can you show or link to the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is `None`:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.normalize('NFD', None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be unicode, not None
```

Check what `stt.stt()` returns, or handle the `None` case.

The generator expression parentheses are optional, but when using `str.join()` it is actually faster to use a list comprehension here (the `str.join()` code *has* to convert the input to a list as it'll need to traverse the list twice):

```
def remove_tildes(s):
   # Remove spanish tildes so there won't be errors with ascii
   return ''.join([
       c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s or u'')
       if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'])
```

where `s or u''` handles the case where `s` is `None` by replacing it with the empty string.

Comment: `c` could also be None

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no it cannot because `unicodedata.normalize()` **always** returns a new `unicode` object.

Comment: True then the function obviously returns None

Comment: Yes, of course, I was going to do this, but i have to wait 5 minutes

Comment: @JavierDelgado, I would figure out why you get None when you are expecting text

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are passing None as the parameter?

Try:

```
def remove_tildes(s):
   if s:
       return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s) 
                       if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))
```